# What is the performance of C++0x forward_list under different scenarios?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been using std::forward_list where I need a list but don't need bidirectional iterators, but it would be nice to see a performance analysis of how forward_list performs under a series of scenarios on a series of configurations, such as;

- forward_list::erase_after() vs list::erase()
- forward_list::push_front() vs list::push_front()
- std::next(forward_list::iterator,n) vs std::next(list::iterator,n)
- forward_list::iterator++ vs list::iterator++

I have seen a lot of these for vectors and arrays, and it would be useful to see it for the newer forward_list as well.

Please only productive answers.

Comment: you can write 50 line code program to profile it

Comment: A non-productive comment: I suspect that any significant difference in performance between `forward_list` and `list` would be difficult to measure and that `forward_list` only makes sense on very memory constrained systems. But maybe some profiling will prove me wrong.

Comment: *"I have seen a lot of these for vectors and arrays, and it would be useful to see it for the newer forward_list as well."* Perhaps it would be more beneficial to compare `forward_list` or `list` with `vector`. There are some highly non-trivial, counterintuitive scenarios due to how these containers handle the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forward_list` does not have an `erase()` method; I assume you mean `erase_after()`.

All pairs of methods in your question have exactly the same asymptotic complexity (`std::next(it, n)` is linear in `n` and the rest are constant-time).

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. There must be some real life performance benefit on conventional systems for implementing forward_list though, right? Otherwise, why did they make it?

Comment: Have a look at Michael Burr's comment to the question, `forward_list` only makes sense in very memory-constrained systems. Remember, that `list` is pretty much exactly the same apart from the back-pointer which allows backwards iteration (and everything that comes with that).